# combining rows into one column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of rows with name leader name and manager name but these records are coming after joining few tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (leader.name), manager.Name 
FROM 
    ref, leader, orgList, manager, modules 
WHERE 
    leader.id = orgList.leaderCode
    AND orgList.dept = ref.id
    AND orgList.manager = manager.id
    AND orgList.id = modules.orgListId
    AND ref.id = 'xyzzz123'
    AND ref.month = 'august'
    AND modules.year = '2018'
```

I get result like this

```
leader_name       manager_name
---------------------------------
 John              Jim
 John              Hiko
 John              Sevu
 John              Celi
 Kerst             Newon
 Kerst             Dollace
```

But I actually want result like this

```
leader_name       manager_name
------------------------------------
John              Jim;Hiko;Sevu;Celi
Kerst             Newon;Dollace
```

I tried pivot and other things but that works only with one table.

Comment: USe STUFF to get your expected result.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.  That doesn't solve your problem, it just brings you up-to-date on SQL syntax.

Comment: @mkRabbani don't know how to use it for multiple tables

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Check this-

**Note:** Use Standard JOIN instead of comma separated JOIN

```
WITH CTE(leader_name,manager_name)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        (leader.name) leader_name, manager.Name  manager_name
    FROM 
        ref, leader, orgList, manager, modules 
    WHERE 
        leader.id = orgList.leaderCode
        AND orgList.dept = ref.id
        AND orgList.manager = manager.id
        AND orgList.id = modules.orgListId
        AND ref.id = 'xyzzz123'
        AND ref.month = 'august'
        AND modules.year = '2018'
)


SELECT 
leader_name ,
manager_name = 
    STUFF
    (
            (
                SELECT ';' + manager_name 
                FROM CTE B
                WHERE A.leader_name = B.leader_name
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
    )
FROM CTE A
GROUP BY leader_name
```